# How can I configure Windows to use the correct resolution for a standard definition TV (SDTV)?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, drivers, tv, edid

## Introduction

I know someone who has a laptop and wants it to output video to a TV. I bought a cheap cable to connect its VGA output to one of the TV's composite video inputs.

The seller of the cable clearly said that the laptop must support TV-out via the VGA socket, but I assumed this would be true. [This assumption may not be correct](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2388).

## Specs

1. GPU: NVIDIA® GeForce® 9300M GS
2. Video outputs: VGA, HDMI
3. Cable: VGA to Composite & S-Video (not active, no scan converter)
4. TV: Standard definition (SD). Non-widescreen. Supports PAL, NTSC and SECAM.

## Problem

The problem I have run into is Windows will not allow me to set a compatible resolution to use for the TV. Consequently, the TV just shows the typical sort of distorted images you get from a mode mismatch. I figure there's no EDID information provided to Windows, so it's just using a generic non-PnP monitor driver.

I looked through Windows' list of built-in monitor drivers, and the closest driver I could find was *Generic Television*. However, even using this driver, Windows seemed to provide the typical list of VGA monitor resolutions. The minimum resolution I could set was 800x600, and the minimum refresh rate was 60Hz.

**I think there could be multiple problems here that I need help with:**

1. The *Generic Television* driver doesn't seem to provide the right modes, namely 480i @ 60Hz and 576i @ 50Hz. I think I need a suitable monitor driver.
2. Windows seems to have a minimum resolution of 800x600, which is too high.
3. Windows seems to have a minimum refresh rate of 60Hz.

It's possible that the last two problems will be resolved in the presence of a suitable monitor driver.

Lastly, I would prefer an option other than using PowerStrip, since it's commercial software.

Comment: I've had no problems running a CRT TV at 1024x768 via composite. The desktop was a bit squished in, but it was all there.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, this is a standard-definition TV, and it just shows a severely distorted image (or just flickering) when it isn't set to an appropriate mode. I couldn't think of the right terminology to explain this when I wrote the question! I've updated it to reflect this.

Comment: Mine was an old CRT too. But the video card handled it directly, so that probably made a difference.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, Oh; I didn't really know they could handle higher resolutions. I think you're definitely right that the video card makes a difference.

Comment: They can't handle higher resolutions; the video card compresses the image in order to fit the television.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, that explains a lot. Thanks.

Comment: *"I obtained a VGA to composite/RCA adaptor"* -- Please be more specific.  You need a (active) converter, not a (passive) adapter.  Some older graphics cards had a built-in "TV output" that converted the VGA to NTSC (aka analog SDTV), which is probably what @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams is referring to.  I've used that to display a (converted) 1024x768 desktop on a TV, but regular text is very hard to discern and read.  It is not a question of resolution.  You need a scan converter.  Without a converter there is no driver or adapter that can convert VGA to a composite TV signal

Comment: @sawdust: Some video cards output a TV signal on one or more of the DE-15 pins; a passive converter is suitable for those. It does require video card support though.

Comment: @sawdust, thanks for your input. I'm confident that the cable I'm using is **passive**. I've updated the question to reflect this. Are you certain that even if I was able to set a matching video mode, such as 480i, it would still not work?

Comment: *"Are you certain..."* - Yes.  Setting up a resolution of 480i only gets you close to the correct sync pulse timings.  But the video information is all wrong for the TV.  VGA transmits the video information as three separate signals for `red`, `green` and `blue` plus two sync signals.  Composite video (aka CVBS) is just one signal that combines `luminance`, `chrominance` and sync information.  This combination of all information in just one signal or wire or channel is why it is called "composite".  There is no device driver to generate a composite video signal from VGA hardware.